# Loop printing twice java

Tags: java, for-loop

I have no idea why my loop is printing twice. I have two separate classes that I have created and for whatever reason I cannot figure out why it's printing twice to the console. I am not sure if it is because I called it wrong in TableTest? Or if I had done something wrong elsewhere. I have run this both in my IDE and my Command Line and I'm still getting the same issue.

```
public class TableTest {
public static void main(String[] args){


    int getBegin, getEnd;


        System.out.println("Enter a number to start with: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        getBegin = input.nextInt();
            while (getBegin < 0){
                System.out.println("Please enter a number greater than 0.");
                getBegin = input.nextInt();
            }
        System.out.println("Enter a number to end with: ");
        getEnd = input.nextInt();
            while (getEnd < 0 || getEnd < getBegin){
                System.out.println("Please enter a number greater than 0. Or greater than your first input.");
                getEnd = input.nextInt();
    }

        MultiplicationTable loop = new MultiplicationTable(getBegin, getEnd);

        loop.printTable(getBegin, getEnd);

    }
}





public class MultiplicationTable {

public MultiplicationTable(int begin, int end){
    printTable(begin,end);
}

void printTable(int begin, int end){

    System.out.println(String.format("%-10s %-10s %-10s", "Number", "Squared" , "Cubed"));

    for (int i = begin; i <= end; ++i){
        System.out.println(String.format("%-10s %-10s %-10s", i, i* i, i*i*i));
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your constructor in MultiplicationTable calls the `printTable` method and then you call it again in the main method

Comment: Ahh! Thank you, I was so confused why that was happening.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `printTable` method twice:

1. In constructor of `MultiplicationTable` class.

   public MultiplicationTable(int begin, int end){
       printTable(begin,end);
   }
2. In `main` method and after geting instance of `MultiplicationTable` class:

   MultiplicationTable loop = new MultiplicationTable(getBegin, getEnd);
   loop.printTable(getBegin, getEnd);

So for these reasons, it executes the `printTable` method twice.